# Blazority does no recognize datagrid model

Tags: blazor

I am trying to create a table in Blazor using the Blazority Datagrid from here: https://blazority.com/datagrid

When I replace the "DemoUser" with my model, I get an error

```
The type or namespace name cannot be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)
```

I trying adding a using statement in the file. Did not fixed the problem.

Code sample:

```
<Datagrid Items="AllContracts">
        <DatagridColumn Title="Id" TRowData="ContractModel" Field="c => c.Id" CanSort="true" />
</Datagrid>
```

Edit: Be aware that my class is in a separate library.

Comment: Please don't use unrelated tags. `clarity` is definitely *not* blazority

Comment: `I trying adding a using statement in the file. Did not fixed the problem.` what was the *actual* `using` statement? What's the namespace of the `ContractModel` class? Does your client project have a reference to the model project?

Comment: ContractModel was in a library references by the web project. The correct using statement was added do Imports. Did not fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Blazority cannot recognize Models outside of the library. Moving the class to a folder inside the same library fixed the problem.

Comment: The grid control has nothing to do with whether a type name is in scope or not. The grid doesn't even exist, much less run, when you compile your application. You fix that by adding a `using` statement, which *does* work, as you just proved. Just make sure you reference the correct project or library. Most likely, the original project didn't have a reference to the library the class was defined (the `Shared` project perhaps?). Or the page didn't have the correct `using` directive.